# What is the name of the grammar structure where people say "V1して + V2しない" meaning "V1しないで + V2する"

Tags: て-form, negation

What I mean is what is happening in this sentence: 宿題を**して行かない**生徒が多いです meaning "There are many students who go (to school) without having done their homework". I would like to know the name of this grammar structure so I can learn more about it.

Comment: I don’t know what the name of that construction is or whether it has a name, but it has something to do with the combination of attendant circumstances (付帯状況) and negation (否定). But what more do you want to learn about it?